# How does `yield` and `await` production parameters expand into `*` and `async` before identifiers

Tags: parsing, ecmascript-6, context-free-grammar, compiler-construction

Can anyone explain how the following production expands into `*` and `async` keywords:

```
BindingIdentifier[Yield, Await]:
   Identifier
   [~Yield]yield
   [~Await]await
```

Based on the TypeScript parsing code I see that it checks for `*` and `async` keywords, so I assume here that `BindingIdentifier_Yield` matches `*identifier` and `BindingIdentifier_Await` matches `async identifier` but I can't seem to trace that expansion using the above grammar.

I know I can expand the identifiers `[Yield, Await]` according to the spec:

> A production may be parameterized by a subscripted annotation of the
>   form “[parameters]”... A parameterized production is shorthand for a
>   set of productions defining all combinations of the parameter names,
>   preceded by an underscore, appended to the parameterized nonterminal
>   symbol

So the above is expanded into:

```
BindingIdentifier:
   Identifier
   [~Yield]yield
   [~Await]await

BindingIdentifier_Yield:
   Identifier
   [~Yield]yield
   [~Await]await

BindingIdentifier_Await:
   Identifier
   [~Yield]yield
   [~Await]await
```

But how then `BindingIdentifier_Yield` and `BindingIdentifier_Await` is expanded into `*` and `async`? I suspect that the explanation is here:

```
[~Yield]yield
[~Await]await
```

but I'm not sure. Any help is welcome!

Comment: It doesn't. I think you may be misunderstanding in this case. The only logic happening in here is saying that those two words are only allowed as identifiers outside of generators or async functions. Like `function* foo(){ var yield; }` and `async function foo(){ var await; }` are not allowed since those are not allowed as `BindingIdentifier`s.

Comment: Are you sure the parsing code you're talking about applies to this grammar? It sounds more like you are looking at code that parses the beginning of a function in general, rather than a BindingIdentifier.

Comment: @loganfsmyth, thanks! yes, indeed I'm looking at the [functionexpression parsing code](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/src/compiler/parser.ts#L4520) and `parseOptionalToken` looks for `AsteriskToken` so I decided to look that grammar of identifier. [Here is](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/index.html#prod-FunctionExpression) the production for fuction expression `functionBindingIdentifier[~Yield, ~Await]`. If you follow `BindingIdentifier` grammar it wil navigate to the grammar I posted

Comment: How is this not a duplicate of [What are \[Yield, Await, In, Return\] in EcmaScript grammar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46022919/what-are-yield-await-in-return-in-ecmascript-grammar)?!

Comment: @Bergi, this question is about particular application of the knowledge I learnt from the linked question. It's as if you have a question `what is promise` and then another `why promise here doesn't return correct result`. I see them  as different questions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The check for the `*` token [in Typescript](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/1edecac0aba9486d8497a5ab592c39fc32a6a635/src/compiler/parser.ts#L4520) exists to handle both

[14.1](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/#prod-FunctionExpression):

```
FunctionExpression[Yield, Await, Default]:
    function BindingIdentifier[?Yield, ?Await]opt ( FormalParameters[~Yield, ~Await] ) { FunctionBody[~Yield, ~Await] }
```

vs

[14.4](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/#prod-GeneratorExpression):

```
GeneratorExpression[Yield, Await, Default]:
    function* BindingIdentifier[?Yield, ?Await]opt ( FormalParameters[+Yield, ~Await] ) { GeneratorBody }
```

since both function and generator expression can be expanded from PrimaryExpression:

```
PrimaryExpression:
    this
    Literal
    ArrayLiteral
    ObjectLiteral
    FunctionExpression       <---------
    ClassExpression 
    GeneratorExpression      <---------
    AsyncFunctionExpression
    RegularExpressionLiteral
    TemplateLiteral
```

These checks also overlap for function declarations, and method syntax.

The production

```
BindingIdentifier [Yield, Await]:
    Identifier
    [~Yield] yield
    [~Await] await
```

expands to

```
BindingIdentifier:
    Identifier
    yield
    await

BindingIdentifier_Yield:
    Identifier
    await

BindingIdentifier_Await:
    Identifier
    yield

BindingIdentifier_Yield_Await:
    Identifier
```

So `yield` and `await` identifiers are not allowed in cases where `+Yield` and/or `+Await` has been used in the grammar. You can see in the examples above, they use

```
FormalParameters[~Yield, ~Await]
FunctionBody[~Yield, ~Await]
```

whereas the generator uses

```
FormalParameters[+Yield, ~Await]
FunctionBody[+Yield, ~Await]
```

Since the generator says `+Yield` instead of `~Yield`, it means that

```
function foo(){ var yield; } // works
function* foo(){ var yield; } // not allowed
```

Comment: thanks a lot for your help! can you please show also in your answer that both `FunctionExpression` and `GeneratorExpression` can be expanded from [PrimaryExpression](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/index.html#prod-PrimaryExpression)

Comment: Added a bit more to the answer FYI.

Comment: amazing explanation, very much appreciate!

Comment: are you by any chance available for mentoring sessions on codementor.io?

Comment: I do, with the same username. I've never actually done it though! Happy to give it a shot.

Comment: great, thanks, will look you up there. how did you learn ecmascript grammar? are you also good with algorithms?

Comment: Yeah I should be able to answer a good portion of the questions you'll have about the spec. I learned  by basically reading the spec a lot over time.

Comment: In the production for `BindingIdentifier_Yield`, the second rhs should be `await`, not `yield`.

Comment: @MichaelDyck Good catch, fixed.